# $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(xy-7)$ is regular

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I have to prove that $R=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(xy-7)$ is regular. So I have to prove that $R$ is local, Noetherian and that
$$dim R= dim_{R \setminus P} P/P²$$
where $P$ is the maximal ideal of $R$.

$R$ is Noetherian because $\mathbb{Z}$ is Noetherian, but why is it a local ring? And how can I prove that
$$dim R \geq dim dim_{R \setminus P} P/P² ?$$

Comment: It shouldn't be that $R$ itself is local, but that all its localizations at prime ideals are regular.

Comment: My book use this definition: A local ring $R$ with maximal ideal $P$ is regular if is Noetherian and $dim R= dim_{R\setminus P} P/P^2$

Comment: That's for local rings. Like having the definition for a curve being smooth at a point, but then you call the curve smooth, when it is smooth at every point.

Comment: So, I didn’t find the maximal ideal because this ring isn’t local. Thank you.